# Is there a way to click on an image and then be directed to somewhere else (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to be able to click on a photo and be directed somewhere else (a URL).

I'm using Image.asset. Is there a way to add an onPressed (or similar) command to this?

```
child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              new Transform(
                transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, 50.0 * (1.0 - percentVisible) ,0.0),
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0),
                  child:
                  new Image.asset(
                    viewModel.heroAssetPath,
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 200.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

I'm only including the relevant portions of my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperlinking an image to an URL in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708753/hyperlinking-an-image-to-an-url-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it in a [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

```
new GestureDetector (
   onTap: () {
      // redirect to URL here
   },
   child: new Image.asset(
      viewModel.heroAssetPath,
      width: 200.0,
      height: 200.0,
   ),
);
```

To redirect you can use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) package.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Wrap your `Image` widget in an `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` and use *onTap/onPressed* event.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Image inside an `InkWell` widget:

```
InkWell(
  child: Image.asset(
           viewModel.heroAssetPath,
           width: 200.0,
           height: 200.0,
          ),
 onTap: () { 
    // Add navigator code here
 }
),
```