# Hyperlinking multiple images to multiple URLs in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, url, flutter-web

Beginner here...
I have already read this: [Hyperlinking an image to an URL in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708753/hyperlinking-an-image-to-an-url-in-flutter)
And this: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

but cannot figure out a reasonable method to add a hyperlink for a GridView of images that I am working with

```
    Container(
              height: 750,
              width: 250,
              child: GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/Img-Aaron.jpg'),
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/Img-Alex.jpg'),
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/Img-Ander.jpg'),
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/Img-Paul.jpg'),
                    color: Colors.black,
```

I want the user to be able to click an image and go to that image's specified URL.

All the example code I've seen out there so far demonstrates only one image and one OnTap: or OnPressed: and usually ends with code like this:

```
    _launchURL() async {
const url = 'https://flutter.io';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

}

Any recommendations or pointers out there about how I could do this simply? For example with a list of Url's like this:

```
const _url1 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplea/';
const _url2 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Exampleb/';
const _url3 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplec/';
const _url4 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Exampled/';
const _url5 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplee/';
const _url6 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplef/';
const _url7 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Exampleg/';
const _url8 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Exampleh/';
const _url9 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplei/';
const _url0 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplej/';
const _url11 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplek/';
const _url12 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplel/';
const _url13 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplem/';
const _url14 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplen/';
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend refactoring the code and separate out the `Container`.
Let's call it `ProfileCard` for now which can contain code like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfileCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  
  const ProfileCard({
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.onTap,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
        child: Image.asset(imagePath),
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in this `onTap`, you can pass that `_launchUrl()` method but with a String in the argument.

```
_launchUrl(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Now, your GridView will look like:

```
Container(
  height: 750,
  width: 250,
  child: GridView.count(
    primary: false,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: <Widget>[
      ProfileCard(imagePath: 'assets/Img-Aaron.jpg', onTap: _launchUrl(_url1)),
      ProfileCard(imagePath: 'assets/Img-Alex.jpg', onTap: _launchUrl(_url2)),
      ProfileCard(imagePath: 'assets/Img-Ander.jpg', onTap: _launchUrl(_url3)),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Using these consts above:

```
const _url1 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplea/';
const _url2 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Exampleb/';
const _url3 = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/Examplec/';
```

I hope this clarifies your query. If you need more help, you can contact me at [ahmadkhan.dev](https://ahmadkhan.dev)

Comment: What a fantastic response. It will take me some time to get the placement of these pieces correct in my application but you have given me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Finally implemented it and got it working! Thanks!

Comment: A pleasure to help!